# Python Pandas: TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern in user defined function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have defined a function which looks like below:

```
def incident_rate(substation,year,events):

    age = conductor_yearly_df.loc[conductor_yearly_df['SUBSTATION']==substation,conductor_yearly_df.columns.str.contains(year)].reset_index(drop=True).values[0][0]
    length = conductor_yearly_df.loc[conductor_yearly_df['SUBSTATION']==substation,conductor_yearly_df.columns.str.contains(year)].reset_index(drop=True).values[0][1]
    temp = events / (age * length) 
    return temp
```

When I call the function in the code (for example: `incident_rate('WB',2019,6)`, it throws following error:

```
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

I am not sure where am I making the mistake. Could anyone please guide me how to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change year to string with `str(year)`, since `str.contains` accept type of string

```
age = conductor_yearly_df.loc[conductor_yearly_df['SUBSTATION']==substation,conductor_yearly_df.columns.str.contains(str(year))].reset_index(drop=True).values[0][0]
```